# If else error I don't understand this error

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

I don't understand this error is it logical error or something else here is the coding " this program should convert riyal to currency that is chosen by the user using multiway if-else

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Convert
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb= new Scanner (System.in);

        double riyal, c;
        int opp;

        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of money in Riyal: ");
        riyal= kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the currency option(1- Dollar, 2- Euro, 3- Yen): ");
        opp= kb.nextInt();

        if(opp==1)

            c=riyal*0.267;
        System.out.print(riyal+" Riyals is converted to "+c" Dollars");

        else if (opp==2)

            c=riyal*0.197;  
            System.out.print(riyal+" Riyals is converted to "+c" Euros");

         else if (opp==3)

            c=riyal*0.27.950;
          System.out.print(riyal+" Riyals is converted to "+c" Yens");

         else
         {
            System.out.println("Invalied opption");
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
error: illegal start of expression
error: 'else' without 'if'
error: ';' expected
error: ')' expected
```

The program that I'm using is Jcreator

Comment: For the record, i don't feel you really tried to solve that error yourself and that you don't deserve that many answers. Especially from thoses top users.

Comment: what kind of error you got?

Comment: @Md.NasirUddinBhuiyan: The error message is at the end of the question.

Comment: you should learn the basic of if-else statement. To use multiple statement in if else you must cover the statement with {} under if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use curly braces if your if blocks have more than a single statement :

```
if(opp==1) {
    c=riyal*0.267;
    System.out.print(riyal+" Riyals is converted to "+c" Dollars");
} else if (opp==2) {    
    c=riyal*0.197;  
    System.out.print(riyal+" Riyals is converted to "+c" Euros");       
} else if (opp==3) {             
    c=riyal*0.27.950;
    System.out.print(riyal+" Riyals is converted to "+c" Yens"); 
} ... and so on ...
```

When you write it without the braces, it's equivalent to:

```
if(opp==1) {
    c=riyal*0.267;
}
System.out.print(riyal+" Riyals is converted to "+c" Dollars");

else if (opp==2)
```

so the `else if` is not related to any `if`.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't marking the start and end the bodies of your `if` statements - wihch means they're just single statements. You've currently effectively got:

```
if(opp==1) {
    c=riyal*0.267;
}
System.out.print(riyal+" Riyals is converted to "+c" Dollars");
else if (opp==2)
```

As you can see, that `else` doesn't "belong" to any `if` block. I'd strongly recommend that you *always* use braces, even for single-statement `if` bodies:

```
if(opp==1) {
    c=riyal*0.267;
    System.out.print(riyal+" Riyals is converted to "+c" Dollars");
} else if (opp==2) {
    ...
} // etc
```

Note that if you get your IDE to format your code, this should all become rather clearer. The indentation that the IDE will apply will show you how things are *actually* being understood...

Comment: Thank you all for responding I've already add block{}  before I post my question and the same error massage appears, so I followed an example in my book.  I may miss something  by mistake

Comment: @SaraAlbuainain: Why didn't you post the actual code that was causing the problem then? Adding the braces (everywhere in your code, not just in the example I gave) *does* fix the problem - it really does...

Answer (score 1):

`if`, `else`, and other flow control statements operate on the **one** statement that follows them. When you have more than one, you use a block (`{}`):

```
if(opp==1) {
    c=riyal*0.267;
    System.out.print(riyal+" Riyals is converted to "+c" Dollars");
}
else if (opp==2) {
// ...
```